# How to hide IntelliJ IDEA's "Background tasks" window using the keyboard?

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

IntelliJ IDEA's *Background Tasks* window can be shown by following *Window* → *Background Tasks* → *Show* in the main menu.

But once it's open, I can only hide the window by clicking on the top right dash button, which requires reaching for the pointing device.

Is there a way to hide IntelliJ IDEAD's *Background Tasks* window using only the keyboard (either by an existing keymap, or by navigating through the main menu)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible at the moment, feel free to [vote for the corresponding issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-216058).